# Sticky header and footer with spring only on content with iOS PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to put together a scaffold for a PWA. I've been looking at Instagram's PWA and they have a sticky header (App Bar) and a sticky footer (Nav Bar) and only the content in the middle scrolls and springs. It also has proper release scroll physics on iOS. This is fantastic.

I have tried to replicate this with Flexbox and I can get the basics of sticky header and footer but the scrolling mechanism is incorrect. For one, you cannot release with scroll inertia (scroll physics are clamping) and two, when you reach scroll extents the header/footer will spring along with it.

Here is an MVCE of my current method which is not acceptable.

http://jsfiddle.net/56cfd93n/21/

```
#page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

#appbar, #navbar {
  background: #eee;
  height: 32px;
}

#content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Here is a link to the Instagram PWA which does not have these issues: https://www.instagram.com

How do I build a basic PWA scaffold (AppBar, Content, NavBar) that performs correctly on iOS, like the Instagram PWA does?

Answer (score 0):

See [Brotkrumen](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen) for a working flex-box solution that does what you want.